# UHF RFID PYTHON CODE?

Tags: pi-3, python, rfid, web-interface

Hi recently I purchased UHF RFID from China supplier

https://ruifanelec.en.alibaba.com/product/60620230740-218430589/Hot_Sell_Free_SDK_Long_Range_Integrated_TCP_IP_UHF_RFID_Reader.html?spm=a2700.8304367.cunta628ec.4.7a565d271Gy5qC

This demo software is not working properly and it is encrypted in Chinese and not functioning properly. I was also looking for an open source software for the above RFID reader, finally, I could not find any, maybe not lucky for the source.
Later decided to buy a Raspberry Pi 3. I thought this can only solve my problem.

**My practical problems;**

RFID reader has been provided an interface of RS232 (cable), unfortunately, I could not able to connect to the RPi. I decided to purchase a USB to Serial converter (Unitech). This is working with windows 10, but I am not sure with RPi. because USB (of the serial converter) would functional on the Pi (if I connect serial converter USB to Pi USB plugin).

Then I decided to connect RFID data 0, 1 cables to GPIO of RPi. You can see the color Yellow and grey are data points.

[image]
[image]

Raspberry Pi 3 input CatLog. 
[image]

[image]

According to my knowledge TDX0 (GPIO14, 08 for yellow cable RFID), and RXD0 (GPIO15, 10 for grey cable RFID) are the GPIO connecting points.

I have not connected the data points yet because I am struck with the Python script. What I output need from the RPi. would be is  UHF tag number, time of tag detection.

I have seen some of the examples from other developers.

**Use Arduino and RS232 Shield to interface Integrated UHF RFID reader LSID-0702**

http://learn.linksprite.com/arduino/shields/use-arduino-and-rs232-shield-to-interface-integrated-uhf-rfid-reader-lsid-0702/

**125 KHz RFID tag reader**

http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/RFID_reader/125kHz_RFID_reader.htm

**Long Range UHF RFID Item Tracking System**

https://www.hackster.io/careypayette/long-range-uhf-rfid-item-tracking-system-fc5372

I am not very good at coding. Can you please help me with the coding!
What I need from you is: If there is any tag near to RFID reader (maximum) 6 meters, accept the signal and note the timing, tag number, and the date. Thank you

Comment: You cannot connect rs232 to the GPIO Serial pins.  RS232 uses negative and positive voltages and  they are higher then the 3.3v logic the pi uses.

Comment: Also this is not a place to ask for free coding. The forum is to ask specific questions about problems you are facing. Please do a little research and learning, and come back if you have a specific problem we can help with

Answer (score 1):

> a USB to Serial converter

As far as I am aware, like many basic USB peripherals, those are reasonably standardized, and a stock linux kernel should have drivers available.

> but I am not sure with RPi. because USB (of the serial converter) would functional on the Pi (if I connect serial converter USB to Pi USB plugin)

It probably will.  Plug it in and check `ls -1 /dev | grep ttyUSB`.  You should get something like `ttyUSB0` back.  You can use `/dev/ttyUSB0` exactly like you use `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/serial0` or whatever it is you normally use to access the GPIO UART.

If it doesn't show up in `/dev`, get rid of the stuff in your question that involves destroying the Pi with inappropriate voltages and edit in the output of `lsusb` with the converter plugged in.  You will need to `apt install usbutils` if this command is not found.